# Demo ads not available in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, iad

I've integrated iAds in my application:

```
ADBannerView *bannaerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
[self adjustBannerView];
bannaerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
bannaerView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannaerView];
```

It's not showing demo advertisements when running iOS 9.

When using iOS 8 I do receive demo advertisements:

[image]

While tapping on the advertisement, it opens some other screens to show the app is connected to iAd properly.

Why am I unable to receive demo advertisements using iOS 9? It's showing a blank space. I tried on device also.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This problem with iOS 9 keeps popping up and disappearing since iOS 9's release. [Report a bug to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/) to help bring it to their attention.

Also, `bannaerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES` is not necessary and you've misspelt *banner*. Check to make sure your Fill Rate is set to 100% too: Go to Settings>Developer>Fill Rate> and set it to 100%.

Comment: where are these settings available ? I have no knowledge about this pls explain it i'll be obliged

Comment: Thanks @Daniel . I have wondered that most of the developers are unable to get iAd, are experiencing the same ? as from last xcode 7.1 , I'm not able to iAds too.

Comment: @SabhaySardana it's in your devices Settings application. Scroll down until you see Developer.

Comment: @SabhaySardana it's not the ultimate solution but can sometimes be the issue. Please submit a bug to Apple with the link I've provided in my answer.

Comment: u got any solution or not ?? @SabhaySardana

Comment: not yet , I think there's a problem from apple's side as the I have seen that in my app's ads request ads are being requested by my app but they are not being filled . I think it's high time we should switch from iad to admob.